# PDFJS: pdfDoc is null

Tags: javascript, html, web, pdf.js

I am trying to declare a custom pdf object. following is the pdf class:

```
function WhiteBoardPdf(canvasContext,url){
    PDFJS.disableWorker = false;

    var pdfDoc=null,
        scale=1,
        pageNum=1;

    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdf(_pdfDoc) {
        console.log('getting pdfDoc');
        pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
        //self.load(_pdfDoc,scale);
        renderPage(pageNum);
    });

    function numberOfPage(){
        console.log('getting number of page');
        return pdfDoc.numPages;
    }

    function renderPage(num){
        var ctx=canvasContext;
        var canvas=ctx.canvas;
        var canvasName=canvas.className;
        var allCanvas=document.getElementsByClassName(canvasName);
        var canvasContainer=document.getElementById("whiteBoardLayerContainer");
        // Using promise to fetch the page
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        for(i=0;i<allCanvas.length;i++){
            allCanvas[i].height=viewport.height;
            allCanvas[i].width=viewport.width;
        }
        canvasContainer.style.width=viewport.width+'px';
        // Render PDF page into canvas context
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
      });
    }

    this.renderPageByPageNum=function(num){
        pageNum=num;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    }

    this.getNumberOfPages=function(){
        return numberOfPage();
    }

    this.getPdfDoc=function(){
        return pdfDoc;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to call the getNumberOfPages() method after I create the WhiteBoardPdf object in the main program. There are the following message shown in console.

```
getting number of page WhiteBoardPdf.js:17
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numPages' of null WhiteBoardPdf.js:18
getting pdfDoc
```

I can not get number of page using the getNumberOfPages() method in the main program or other class. Can anyone teach me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can call numberOfPage() only after `function getPdf(_pdfDoc) {` is called. Read about Promises/A+ at http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/